bundle install cannot load such file
When I try bundle install or RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=1 bundle exec pod install in my project I get this error. Mac on chip M2
/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/bundle:25:in `load': cannot load such file -- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.15/exe/bundle (LoadError)
        from /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'

I have already reinstalled gem, but it doesn't help:
My ruby ver:
ruby 3.3.3 (2024-06-12 revision f1c7b6f435) [arm64-darwin23]

/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/ruby

/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/gem

gem list bundler 

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (default: 2.5.15)

.zpfofile:
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-17.jdk/Contents/Home

export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
exportPATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

if [ -d "/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin" ]; then
  export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH
  export PATH=`gem environment gemdir`/bin:$PATH
fi


I had the same issue today and it was that I had multiple versions of Bundler installed.
I ran, gem uninstall bundler --all --force && gem install bundler and it resolved the issue for me.

Worked for me too!

Thanks! works on my MacOS 13.5.2 (22G91)

The version of rubygem and bundle maybe not matched.
You can uninstall the bundler and reinstall it again by @Ben Simmons had mention above
gem uninstall bundler --all --force && gem install bundler
